# Rotate 3d car with android animations

Tags: java, android, 3d, android-animation

[image]

In this example I want rotate this car to see the car from the side.

I have to do it with swipe or drag listeners.

Could anyone tell me how could I create this animation

What I tried:

I tried to detect swipe left and right listeners and after that I called animation that load 30 images seems like it rotating.

But as I see is very bad approach.

Could anyone tell me how could I do this not using gaming library like libgdx?

I don't have much experience working with 3d objects.

Comment: You should use OpenGL for android 3D work. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

Comment: I have to draw this car in 3d or I can use static images ?

Comment: if you have a spritesheet of the car, which is a fairly small size, you should be fine looping through the animations, depending on the frames you need.

Comment: How a 2D image can become 3D ? You have to use 3D library and openGL widely used library for 3D graphics and supported through android.

Comment: Draw your car in a 3D software, such as the open source [Blender 3D](https://www.blender.org/)

Comment: You can then freely move, rotate and scale your 3D object by using  OpenGL.

Comment: See what I mean in this nice red Mini video, made in Blender: https://vimeo.com/67960559

Comment: Free model to download: http://tf3dm.com/download-page.php?url=mini-cooper-16157

Comment: @FrankN.Stein how to integrate moder into android app. Is android supported .blend extension?

Comment: No. You must import the blend file in Blender. Then export it as obj (which is a standard 3D object format and it's supported by OpenGL).

Comment: JMonkeyEngine has a blender importer. You can import a WaveFront OBJ model with LibGDX too. Both uses OpenGL ES under the hood. JOGL works under Android too and JOGL-Utils contains several OBJ importers. What is wrong with LibGDX? It's a good solution.

Comment: Moreover, LibGDX is **portable** (Android, iOS, ...)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein exported obj file is about 250 mb is it okay?

Comment: No. It's far too much. You should retopologize your model to a lower polygon version. But to do so, you need to follow some tutorial on YouTube. Blender has a `higher learning curve` than 3DS Max, but it's far `more powerful`!!